# Small caps in footnote in title (amsart)

Tags: macros, footnotes, titles, small-caps, amsart

I am trying to add a footnote to a title in [`amsart`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart) in small caps, but constantly end up with upper case characters (even in math mode).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\title{ text \footnote{ text }}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

How can I get small caps in the footnote?

Comment: `\title{ text \footnote{\normalfont\scshape\lowercase{text}}}`. But a footnote on the title seems odd.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina they still are printed in uppercase

Comment: If it *is* necessary to place a footnote on a title, the AMS recommendation is to use `\footnotemark` in the title, and a separate `\footnotetext` after it.  You'll also have to provide an alternate for the running heads to omit the footnote material; `\markright{...}` will do the right thing with `amsart`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Could you please make that into an answer with some sample code using the `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`... Thanks,

Comment: @barbarabeeton I would even upvote an answer. ;-)

Comment: @kan -- i've got a small problem. `\footnotemark` doesn't produce anything; it just vanishes.  i'm afraid i'll have to regress to `\textsuperscript`, but first i need to figure out why the `\foornotemark` is disappearing.  when i do, i'll post an answer.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- see comment to kan.  sigh.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Maybe this is naïve but doesn't `\@maketitle` do `\@adminfootnotes` which does `\let\@makefnmark\relax  \let\@thefnmark\relax` ahead of `\@settitle` ?

Comment: @cfr -- you're quite correct about why the footnote mark is disappearing.  but simply patching that away will corrupt the intended style of the administrative footnotes (`\thanks`, etc.).  i'm not in a position to experiment for at least a week -- out of office on holiday, but i'll try to figure out what to do when i return; this simply got buried and i lost track.  egreg is correct about the "extra surgery".

Answer (score 3):

The workaround is quite simple, but there will be no footnote marker:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\myfootnotetitle{\spaceskip=0pt \scshape I want this in Small Caps}
\title{Title\footnote{\protect\myfootnotetitle}}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\maketitle

\vspace*{\fill}
{\footnotesize\myfootnotetitle\par} % for checking

\end{document}
```

There are two problems: one is to protect against untimely expansion (the argument to `\title` is passed to `\MakeUppercase`) and also that in the text `\spaceskip` is set to a nonzero value.

[image]

Adding a footnote marker requires deeper surgery. A simple workaround for getting an asterisk as a footnote mark is as follows.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definetitlefootnote}[1]{%
  \newcommand\addtitlefootnote{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{$^{*}$}%
    \footnote{\protect\@titlefootnotetext}
  }%
  \newcommand\@titlefootnotetext{\spaceskip=\z@skip $^{*}$#1}%
}
\makeatother

% Just to make a short page for viewing the result
\setlength{\textheight}{6cm}
\calclayout

\begin{document}

\definetitlefootnote{\scshape I want this in Small Caps}
\title{Title\addtitlefootnote}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\maketitle

Some text with a footnote\footnote{Whatever}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what if `\thanks` or `\subjclass` is needed?  what will they look like?  (i'm on holiday, and not able to check anything.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I really don't know and, honestly, I don't think I want to try.

Comment: but the absence of footnote markers in the top matter is one of the key specifications of `amsart`.  if your answer makes markers appear for those elements, the answer can't be "correct" (at least not if the article is to be published in an ams journal).

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know, that's why I wouldn't bother: apparently the OP is using `amsart` for her/his own purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to keep the footnote marker too.  You need to save the definitions and restore them just before issuing the `\footnotemark` command.  There is then some juggling to get the correct counter values.

Here is the title:

[image: Title]

And here are the footnotes, showing `\thanks` etc. are not disturbed.

[image: Footnotes]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\let\mymakefnmark\@makefnmark
\let\mythefnmark\@thefnmark

\newcommand{\restorefn}{\let\@makefnmark\mymakefnmark
\let\mythfnmakr\@thefnmark}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title text\restorefn\footnotemark}
\author{A. N. Author}
\date{\today}
\thanks{Thanks}
\maketitle
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{\scshape Footnote.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution provides a little more automation and keeps the user interface as is, so to say that you can keep on writing `\title[short text]{text\footnote{text}}`.

The basic idea is to disable that the internal macro `\@adminfootnotes` disables the usual footnote mechanism through

```
\xpatchcmd\@adminfootnotes{\let\@makefnmark\relax}{}{}{}
```

and then use the `\footnotemark`-`\footnotetext` duo.The mark is built through something like `\title{...\fotenotemark}` and the `\footnotetext` is declared outside to make sure that it does not get affected by the uppercasing. Latter is accomplished by a patch simple patch to `\maketitle`:

```
\xapptocmd\maketitle{%
  \stepcounter{footnote}
  \ifx\@empty\titlefn\else
    \footnotetext{\scshape\titlefn}\fi}{}{}
```

`\titlefn` is the storage of the footnote text that gets gathered by `\footnote{...}` in a redefined version of `\title` (note that `\footnote` here just serves as delimiter):

```
\def\title@aux#1\footnote#2#3{%
  \global\let\shorttitle\@tempa
  \gdef\titlefn{#2}
  \ams@title{#1\ifx\@empty\titlefn\else\protect\footnotemark\fi}
  \ifx#3\footnote\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter#3\fi
}
```

In this redefinition, of course, also the `\footnotemark` is introduced.

[image: output1_crop]

[image: output2_crop]

### Complete code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@adminfootnotes{\let\@makefnmark\relax}{}{}{}
\xapptocmd\maketitle{%
  \stepcounter{footnote}
  \ifx\@empty\titlefn\else
    \footnotetext{\scshape\titlefn}\fi}{}{}
\let\ams@title\title
\def\title{\@dblarg\title@}
\def\title@[#1]#2{\gdef\@tempa{#1}\title@aux#2\footnote{}}
\def\title@aux#1\footnote#2#3{%
  \global\let\shorttitle\@tempa
  \gdef\titlefn{#2}
  \ams@title{#1\ifx\@empty\titlefn\else\protect\footnotemark\fi}
  \ifx#3\footnote\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter#3\fi
}
\makeatother

\title{text\footnote{text}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%for testing purposes
\vfill
\footnotesize\scshape\hskip3.5pt text
\end{document}
```